# Configuring the AWS Pinpoint Voice ConfigurationSet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I'm attempting to use the AWS JS SDK to fire off a voice call.  What I can't figure out is what the `ConfigurationSetName` is, or where in the AWS Console it is configured.

For example:

```
    await pinpoint.sendVoiceMessage({
      CallerId: '+12025550184',
      ConfigurationSetName: '***WHAT GOES HERE??***',
      Content: {
        SSMLMessage: {
          LanguageCode: 'en-US',
          Text: '<speak>Hello!</speak>',
          VoiceId: 'Joanna'
        }
      },
      DestinationPhoneNumber: '+12025550150',
      OriginationPhoneNumber: '+12025550184'
    }).promise();
```

All I've been able to find is the [REST API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint-sms-voice/latest/APIReference/v1-sms-voice-configuration-sets.html).  This doesn't explain where to set one up in the AWS Console in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did find a way to do this in the Console, but I did find that the API was much simpler than I expected.  As I currently don't need any call progress notifications, I was able to make an empty config set easily:

```
await pinpoint.createConfigurationSet({
  ConfigurationSetName: 'my-config-set-name'
}).promise();
```